# Let $1 < \alpha <2$ and $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R},x \mapsto |x|^\alpha.$ Show that $f \in C^1$ and is $f \in C^2$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

In the above $| \cdot |$ referes to the euklidian norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and in our lecture we use $C^n$ as all n times differentiable functions.

My Idea was to write $|x|^a = \left( \left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^n \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \right)^a = \left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^n \right)^{\frac{a}{2}}$ Then derive the above to get: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} |x|^a=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}(x_1^2 + ... + x_j^2+ ... + x_n^2)^\frac{a}{2} = x_ja(x_1^2 + ... + x_j^2+ ... + x_n^2)^{-\left(1-\frac{a}{2}\right)}$. Since $1 < \alpha < 2$ the only point, where this function is not in $C^1$ in $0$. So there we take a look at $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{ \left( \sum_{i=1}^n h^2 \right)^\frac{a}{2}}{h} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \ n^\frac{\alpha}{2}*h^{\alpha - 1} = 0$, because $1 < a$. Therefore $f$ is differentiable.

Would this explanation work? Or could it be improved? And how do I show that $f$ is or is not in $C^2$ Thank you for your help already :).

Comment: Your definition of the derivative is not correct. $h$ is a real number. How do you add it to an element of $\mathbb R^n$? If you add it to every component, then you take the derivative along $(1,1,...,1)$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Would it work, if I don’t write $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{ \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n h^2 \right)^\frac{a}{2}}{h}$ but instead $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{|h|} = \frac{|h|^\alpha}{|h|} = |h|^{\alpha - 1}$? And because $1 < \alpha$ that is no problem, and the derivative in that point is still $0$?

Comment: I still don't get how you want to add $h\in\mathbb R$ to $0=(0,0,0,...,0)\in\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: I thought you could proofe continuity like that, if $h$ is an arbitrary vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which approaches $0$. Or am I wrong there?

Comment: When you take the derivative in an n-dimensional space, you need to specify the direction. Let's assume that you are in 2D, say a regular map, where $f(x,y)$ is the height above sea level. Assume that your origin is at $x=y=f(0,0)=0$. The derivative is the slope of the terrain. If you go along the shore, the change in height is zero. If you go away from the water, the derivative is positive. If you go straight into the water, the derivative is negative. Which direction you choose?

Comment: Thank you. But what would I need to show than? Does this even show that the function is continuous than?